# net localgroup Administrators shows user names multiple times

Tags: user-accounts

I am seeing this kind of output when I run `net localgroup Administrators`

```
MYDOMAIN\user1
MYDOMAIN\myuserid
MYDOMAIN\myuserid
MYDOMAIN\someotheridIdontrecognize
```

I cannot delete `someotheridIdontrecognize` via `net localgroup Administrators someotheridIdontrecognize /delete` but I can add another account with same id as `someotheridIdontrecognize` with `net localgroup Administrators someotheridIdontrecognize /add`.

now it gets listed twice

```
MYDOMAIN\someotheridIdontrecognize
MYDOMAIN\someotheridIdontrecognize
```

Is there anyway to find out what SID each of these accounts are associated with and why I am unable to remove those useraccounts ?

Particularly troubling is that there seem to be two accounts with the same id as my login, so I afraid to even try to delete one of them!

any troubleshooting help greatly appreciated. I am on XP SP3 workstation connected ot `MYDOMAIN`